# Add space between Number and String

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string Like this

"My Train Coming on Track 10B on 6A and string test with 11S"

Now i want to Add space between Number like 11 and Char B and so on
 i want to like this

"My Train Coming on Track 10 B on 6 A and string test with 11 S"

using C#. is there any logic for that.
thank

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With a regex:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<=\d)(?=\p{L})", " ");
```

This replaces the *"empty space"* between a digit (`(?<=\d)`) and a letter (`(?=\p{L})`) with a space.

A different method without the lookarounds would be:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(\d)(\p{L})", "$1 $2");
```

In this case, it replaces the last digit and the first letter with the pattern `$1 $2`, inserting a space in the process.

Answer (score 3):

The Above answer is correct But according to requirement we have to use that like :

```
  var result = Regex.Replace("4A", @"(?=\p{L})(?<=\d)", " ");
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Actually that's the same thing, the order of the lookarounds doesn't matter since they're zero-length assertions.